# Firefox Middle Mouse Button Scroll

Tags: firefox, mouse

How can I get the middle mouse button to behave correctly in Ubuntu? Clicking the middle button does not show the arrow which allows me to scroll the page by moving the mouse.

Information:

1. Firefox 3.6.8
2. Mouse: Microsoft Intellimouse Explorer 3.0

Answer (score 141, accepted):

For recent versions of Firefox (version 96+) see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/993672/124466) answer.

---

### Original answer

*Edit ➜ Preferences ➜ Advanced ➜ Check 'Use autoscrolling'*

[image]

Comment: Works for me only if smooth scrolling is disabled.

Comment: Worked for me even with smooth scrolling enabled. Kubuntu 14.10 Firefox 29. Really usefull when using a stylus!

Comment: Great to know this can be switched off.

Comment: In `about:config` this is listed as `general.autoScroll` - To be set to `true` to activate.

Answer (score 27):

*Edit 2024-01-16:* this answer is verified with Firefox 121.0.1

*Edit 2022-01-28:* this answer is verified with Firefox 96.0b3

*Edit 2020-11-23:* this answer is verified with Firefox 62.0.3

*Edit 2018-03-14:* this answer is verified with Firefox 58.02

Just to precise, since version **57** of Firefox the path is the following: ***Menu ➜ Preferences ➜ General***, then all the way down in the ***Browsing*** section check the box ***Use auto scrolling***.
You can also just type *auto* in the search field once you're in the *Preferences* window.

See this screenshot:

[image: Activation of the auto scrolling with the middle button of the mouse]

Comment: Works also in Firefox 83.