# Mouse wheel click scrolling in Firefox

Tags: firefox, mouse, mouse-wheel

Just installed Ubuntu 11.10. Been a while since I used any distro and I'm very impressed.

To be difficult, does anyone know how to enable the middle mouse button scroll option when browsing? I don't know if this is an OS level thing or browser config. option.

In Windows, you can usually click the mouse wheel to bring up a scroll icon when using browsers. This allows you to scroll by moving the mouse instead of the mousewheel.

I have RSI and find this method less taxing...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox Middle Mouse Button Scroll](http://askubuntu.com/questions/908/firefox-middle-mouse-button-scroll)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Firefox

You can use some firefox options to both disable the default action which is to paste on clicking the middle-mouse button and also to turn on auto-scrolling.

First - in the Firefox - Preferences - Advance settings ensure you have the following options checked:

- Use Autoscrolling
- Use Smooth scrolling

Then in the Awesome bar type `about:config`

Search for *autoscroll `and double click *general.AutoScroll` to change from "false" to "true"

Now search for *middlemouse*

- middlemouse.contentLoadURL = false
- middlemouse.openNewWindow = false
- middlemouse.paste = false

Then restart firefox

When you middle click you should now see this symbol to scroll:

[image]

Comment: Direct, concise and accurate. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

## System-wide, on ThinkPads

On IBM/Lenovo ThinkPads that have a Trackpoint (red mini-joystick dot in the middle of the keyboard), a similar mechanism can be configured system-wide. It is called "mouse wheel emulation". With this, pressing the middle mouse button and pushing the trackpoint in any direction will scroll up / down / left / right.

To configure this, the following should go into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-trackpoint-tweaks.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "ThinkPad TrackPoint"
    MatchProduct    "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option      "EmulateWheel"      "true"
    Option      "EmulateWheelButton"    "2"
    Option      "XAxisMapping"      "6 7"
    Option      "YAxisMapping"      "4 5"
EndSection
```

[[source](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/xorg.conf.d#Mausrad-Emulation-von-Trackpoints)]

The same can also be configured with the `gpointing-device-settings` application under "Use wheel emulation".