# How do I turn around my object in blender?

Tags: 14.04, mouse, blender

When I switched to Ubuntu, I got blender with `apt-get` and launched it. It's good, but I can't get one thing: I used the middle mouse button to turn while using Blender in my previous operating system, and it doesn't work now in Ubuntu.

How to I turn around my object?

Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr using blender 2.69 from apt repo.

Comment: Does the middle mouse button work elsewhere (e.g. [autoscrolling in Firefox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95267/mouse-wheel-click-scrolling-in-firefox))? This may just be a problem with blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Blender -> `File` -> `User preferences` -> `3D View`

[image]

Comment: Ok. I figured out that it works if I use a mouse. But without a mouse???

Comment: @user2548592 can't you map a keyboard shortcut to `Rotate View`?