# Scroll with Middle Click

Tags: mouse, google-chrome, mouse-scroll

Can I use the middle click mouse button so I can scroll down faster, like in Windows?

When I am in Windows and I press the middle click somewhere I can scroll in, a 4-way pointer shows on the screen, and when I move the mouse in any direction, the window will scroll in that direction even without continuing to press the middle button.

Is there anything like this in Ubuntu? How can I do this, especially in Chrome!

Comment: i guess this is related to each separate application. are you talking about internet browsers only? for ff see http://askubuntu.com/q/908/47206

Comment: Check [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/868173/349837). Works with any application without the need of install anything.

Comment: Maybe it's not a duplicate because some people(me included) would like this feature in non browser aplications, for example Nautilus.

Answer (score 47):

It is natively available in Firefox. In recent versions (tested in version 106.0.1),
Open the page `about:config` and set `general.autoScroll` -> `true`

---

### **Original answer.**

It is native in Firefox, at least 41.0.

Go to Preferences ➜ Advanced ➜ General ➜ Browsing ➜ "Use autoscrolling".

On newer versions: Settings ➜ General ➜ Browsing ➜ "Use autoscrolling".

Comment: Yes, those instructions worked for me in Firefox 46.0.1 on Xenial.

Comment: Works on Firefox Quantum 60.0.1 for Ubuntu

Comment: `about:config` -> general.autoScroll -> true (77.0.1, Ubu 20.04 LTS x86_64)

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is where I can also switch OFF this annoyance. :)

Answer (score 22):

The [AutoScroll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoscroll/occjjkgifpmdgodlplnacmkejpdionan?hl=en) extension for Chrome (Chromium) achieves this. After a single click of the middle mouse button the cursor changes, and moving the mouse in a direction will cause the window to scroll in that direction even without continuing to press the middle button. Scrolling stops when a mouse button is pressed (left, centre, or right).

Comment: same as the other answer

Comment: Better extension

Comment: Works like a charm and without side-effects when opening links in new tab

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Chrome or Chromium, you can install [this chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/middlebuttonscroll/ibehnpdcgpabccnlefccelhblhphbbpl) that will enable you scrolling with only the middle button of the mouse, however you have to continue holding the middle button down while scrolling

Answer (score 3):

Not really. There are some things I have see to make this kind of work, but I have never seen a true working config.

[This article](http://www.conrad.id.au/2011/08/middle-mouse-button-scrolling-on-linux.html) looks at adding the ability to scroll using the TrackPoint in a laptop, by adding a config file into the `xorg.conf.d/` folder.

The theory should be the same, but I have never personally seen this work the way you want it to.