# Scrolling with middle mouse button down

Tags: mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

Just installed my first ever ubuntu distro and immedetially noticed that I cannot hold down the middle mouse button while moving the mouse up / down / sideways to scroll.

How can I turn it on?

Comment: Do you mean like in Firefox?   See https://askubuntu.com/questions/908/firefox-middle-mouse-button-scroll

Comment: This is sometimes called Autoscroll in case you are trying to google for it, and it originated in browsers such as Firefox and Google Chrome but is now implemented in many places in modern OSes.

Answer (score 0):

this question is partly answered here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1180748/152287
You can do it via xinput or in a config file, see the linked answer.

You'll need to know the device name (use `xinput list`) and you'll need to know how your buttons are numbered.

you can see which button is clicked interactively with `libinput-debug-events` (you may need to do `sudo apt install libinput-tools`

check the button name against `xinput list 15` but use the actual device id instead of 15 (device IDs are in `xinput list`). You need to know the button number. The list of button names reported by `xinput list` is in order (I think), starting with button number 1.